# OpenGL window goes black

Tags: c++, opengl

During developement an OpenGL-based point cloud renderer I faced a very disturbing problem.

My first approach was to visualize point clouds directly - in a single DrawArrays() command I was rendering over 15 mln point cloud. Everything was fine until I had enough memory on my VRAM to store a whole point cloud - if not I recieved an error from my Nvidia OpenGL driver telling me that my computer does not meet application specification.

So I've searched a little and I've learned that I have to divide my point cloud in a number of chunks and call DrawArray() for every each of them. So to test it I created a point cloud containing about 60 000 points which I was loading hundreds of times to simulate the behaviour described earlier.

After number of calls instead of an OpenGL driver error my opengl window just turned black. When I changed number of points in a chunk to 40 000, I've managed to load and display over 600 mln points without a blackscreen.

So I have a number of questions:

1. Why is something like this happening in the first place?
2. How can I avoid such a behaviour?
3. How can I predict such a behaviour?
4. Why there is no opengl error (yes I have checked) when something like this happens?

My point cloud is basicly:

```
std::vector<Point3D<float>> vfLXYZ; 
std::vector<Point4D<unsigned char>> vucRGBA;
```

Where:

```
template <class T>
union Point4D
{
    T data[4];
        struct{
            T R;
            T G;
            T B;
            T A;
        };
};

template <class T>
union Point3D
{
    T data[3];
        struct{
            T x;
            T y;
            T z;
        };
};
```

OpenGL contex creation:

```
bool OpenGLContext::create30Context(HDC hdc) {
    this->hdc = hdc;

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd; 
    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR)); 
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR); 
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW; 
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA; 
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE; 

    int nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd); 
    if (nPixelFormat == 0) 
        return false;

    bool bResult = SetPixelFormat(hdc, nPixelFormat, &pfd); 
    if (!bResult) 
        return false;

    HGLRC tempOpenGLContext = wglCreateContext(hdc);
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, tempOpenGLContext); /

    GLenum error = glewInit(); 
    if (error != GLEW_OK) 
        return false;

    int attributes[] = {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4, 
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2, 
        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB,WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB, 
    WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,WGL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0
    };

    if (wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context") == 1) { 
        hrc = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hdc, NULL, attributes); 
        wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL); 
        wglDeleteContext(tempOpenGLContext); 
        wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc); 
    }
    else {
        hrc = tempOpenGLContext; 
        return false;
    }

    int glVersion[2] = { -1, -1 }; /
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &glVersion[0]);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &glVersion[1]); 

    return true; 
}
```

Buffers initialization (loop over all point clouds):

```
glBindVertexArray(pxCloudHeader.uiVBA);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pxCloudHeader.xVBOs.uiVBO_XYZ); 
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iPointCount * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, &p3DfXYZ->data[0], GL_STREAM_DRAW); 
        glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); 

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pxCloudHeader.xVBOs.uiVBO_RGBA); 
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iPointCount * sizeof(GLubyte) * 4, &p4DfRGBA->data[0], GL_STREAM_DRAW); 
        glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); 

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Point cloud rendering (loop over all point clouds) :

```
glBindVertexArray(pxCloudHeader.uiVBA);
        // iLOD is a Level Of Detail
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pxCloudHeader.xVBOs.uiVBO_XYZ);
        glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float) * iLOD, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pxCloudHeader.xVBOs.uiVBO_RGBA);
        glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(unsigned char)*iLOD, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, pxCloudHeader.iPointsCount / iLOD);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Main rendering function:

```
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   

    glClearDepth(fFar); 

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    RenderPointCloud();

    SwapBuffers(hdc);
```

My rendering code is hudge, so I'm posting olny things I believe are relevenat to my problem. If you want to know more (shaders code etc.) please write in comments and I will edit my post. I assure you that beside this problem rendering works just fine.

Also I have noticed that when my opengl window going black application does not stop working - Point cloud rendering loop is executing bu MUCH SLOWER than to be expected. Also my single-threaded application is starting to behave like two-threaded - it consumes two times as many CPU usage % than before black-window crash.

Some other informations:

- I'm using VS2013 and x64 compiler,
- have 32GB RAM,
- have 2 GB VRAM (GeForce GTX 760M),
- have newest graphic cards drivers

Comment: I think that the new NVIDIA driver is the culprit, so try to disable `threaded optimization` inside of `NVIDIA Control Panel`

Comment: @Nazar554: Thanks for the advice. I turned off threaded optimization, but problem still exists. After rendering several frames window goes black and  processor usage is on normal single-thread level